# Zoomable FrameLayout got absolute width and height but Views in it do not match these dimensions

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Okey, so hello everyone.

I am pretty new to app developing.

**Introduction:**

In my app I have activity with ***RelativeLayout***. In this layout I have *zoomable* ***FrameLayout***. In this layout I have to have only one layout. In my case It is another ***RelativeLayout***. Finally in this layout I have number of ***ImageView***s. Purpose of this activity is show layers of map (*drawables*) via switches.

Code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorDarkBlueGrey"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      <com.example.cotwcompanion.ZoomableView
        android:id="@+id/zoomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mapBCG"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:contentDescription="@string/map_name"/>
            
              <!-- Here I generate other ImageViews with 'same' attributes -->

          </RelativeLayout>

       </com.example.cotwcompanion.ZoomableView> 

    <!-- Here are other layouts -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Problem:**

My problem is more or less visual. I would like to show these layers (1:1 ratio) as big as display allows (vertically). Therefor I need to overlap display's width.

**What I need It to look like:**
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDzjI.jpg)

***What I have tried:***

- I thought FrameLayout would do it. So I tried to set its ***width***
  and ***height*** programmatically, so It fits screen height and has
  the same width, because of 1:1 ratio mentioned before. If I try to *log* these dimensions, it seems like all is set. Because
  of ***match_parent*** attribute in ***ImageView***s and their parent ***RelativeLayout***, It should therefor do everything else and stretch these Views to fill ***FrameLayout***. But everything just
  only fits screen width.
  **Image of result here:**
  [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOMxQ.jpg)

Code here:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height, height);
FrameLayout frame = findViewById(R.id.zoomView);
frame.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

- I tried the same method with normal ***FrameLayout*** but got same
  result.
- I also tried to exchange ***FrameLayout*** with
  ***HorizontalScrollView*** and custom *zoomable* ***ImageView***. This worked more or less well, but problem was when I zoomed the map.
  Horizontal scroll disrupt every movement with zoomed map. Therefor I
  tried to create *custom* ***HorizontalScrollView*** with methods to
  disable scroll. Even when I catched *zoomed state* from ***ImageView***
  and set scroll to *notEnabled*, It still did not work.

And there you go. Like I said zooming methods and everything other works. I just need to somehow have bigger View than display allows.

---

**EDIT [21.11.2020]:**

So as Daxi [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937867/zoomable-framelayout-got-absolute-width-and-height-but-views-in-it-do-not-match/64941865#64941865) I tried to change ***RelativeLayout*** in ***ZoomableLayout*** to ***ConstraintLayout***. I also changed ***ZoomableLayout*** to *extend* from ***ConstraintLayout***. That almost solved my problem. However I could not scroll to left and right. I could only zoom. So I took one of my last tried solution and wrapped ***ZoomableView*** with ***HorizontalScrollView***. Everything seemed okey. However I now just cannot scroll to the very 'start' or 'end' of the ***ImageView***. It seems like I can only scroll within the *base width* of ***HorizontalScrollView*** and not *width* of ***ImageView***. So I now need to solve this problem.

Code here:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <HorizontalScrollView>
    <ZoomableView extends ConstraintLayout>
      <ConstraintLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        .
        .
      </ConstraintLayout>
    </ZoomableView>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
  .
  .
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

*I am so sorry if this is somehow a duplicate of other problem already described on stackoverflow, but I searched for solution over two days now and still did not find any. Maybe I am bad finder. If this will be the case, feel free to tell me. I will delete it if needed.*

If there will be some pretty fine answer and solution I would really appreciate It. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using [ConstraintLayouts](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)? If yes, you could use it like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapBCG"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/map_name"/>

        <!-- Here I generate other ImageViews with 'same' attributes -->
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, I am not sure how exactly this will interact with your ZoomableView

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Daxi. I tried to change RelativeLayout to ConstraintLayout. Also I changed ZoomableView to extend from ConstraintLayout. I wrapped everything with HorizontalScrollView. Now I just cannot scroll to the very start or end of the ImageView probably because of width of HorizontalScrollView. Everything is explaned in the EDIT part.